# apt & homebrew comparison

Tags: apt, homebrew

Apologies for punting this to the group for answers, rather than spending solitary research time on this.

I am fairly familiar, at least as a user, with apt via my time spent developing on Ubuntu. However, I am attempting to become *as* effective developing on a Mac and so thought I should understand the similarities and differences between apt and homebrew.

I also understand that this is a pretty broad question, hopefully it will not be down-voted for that reason.

I really am just interested in understanding how best to transfer my experience with what seems like a pretty well thought out package management system (apt), and not struggle with the lack of a native package manager on Mac.

Comment: My understanding is that for the most part, `apt` gets precompiled packages and installs them, while `brew` tends to actually get source code and compile locally.  But generally speaking, for the most part they work more or less similarly with regard to the user experience.